# Проверка на повторяющуюся информацию, запрошенную в БД

Tags: java, jtable

Имеется приложение, которое отображает результат селекта из таблицы, которая находится в базе данных Оракл. Каждый три секунды запрос повторяется и в приложении вновь появляются те же самые записи. Напрягает, что таблица моргает каждые 3 секунды когда обновляет строки, а данные в них те же. Хочется чтобы таблица автоматически обновлялась в приложении только тогда, когда результат селекта будет с изменениями. Вот приложение (запрос вверху приложения):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

так же прикладываю код в котором происходит запрос к базе данных и наполняется таблица JTable - DefaultTableModel с результатами селекта.
Как сделать проверку на то, что данные те же и не надо заполнять Jtable теми же записями каждые 3 секунды, а только если будет хотя бы одно изменение в этих же трёх секундах? В таблице БД у каждой строки свой уникальный id, который я здесь не использовал..

```
static void select() {
    try {
        PreparedStatement st = connect.prepareStatement(
                Gui.JStatement.getText() + where_clause +
                        " AND fl_text LIKE '" + Gui.likeTextField.getText() +
                        "' ORDER BY " + order_by + " " + sorting);

        ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery();
        while (rs.next()) {
            amount = Gui.model.getRowCount() + 1;
            String fl_date = rs.getString("fl_date");
            String fl_text = rs.getString("fl_text");

            Object[] row = new Object[]{
                    amount,
                    fl_date,
                    fl_text
            };
            Gui.model.addRow(row);
        }
        st.close();
```

Comment: Перечитал несколько раз и что то ничего не понял.

Comment: А что такое model? Что такое fl_id,  и почему оно  было Int, а становится String? Почему запрос не имеет  where?  Что такое _таблица лога в Оракл_? В заголовке _таблицы в Оракл_ это то  же самое или что-то другое?  _иначе она просто мигает_ - что мигает, таблица, или это слэнг? И так в каждой фразе. Попробуйте пояснить вашу задачу както по другому, и в самом вопросе, а не комментарием.

Comment: Сделано..согласен.. не смог сразу правильно изложить мысли...заработался..

Comment: Теперь понятнее. По моему надо сохранять max(id). Если он изменится, то добавлять только строки 'id>maxId', и ничего не делать - если не изменился.

Comment: Так а куда записать max id и как его вызвать?  Отдельным селектом?

Comment: В смысле,  куда записать и как вызвать? Значения обычно сохраняются в переменной, переменную нельзя вызвать. Или я не понял ваш последний комментарий.

Comment: Решил вопрос, спасибо! Я сделал 2 новых запроса к БД с разницей в 1000 миллисекунд  с запросом max(id) и в основном третьем запросе сделал проверку на их равенство. Если не равны - выполнять третий запрос.

Comment: Да, можно и так. Я бы сохранил в статическую переменную последний id (это и есть max), в основной запрос бы добавил в условие `fl_id>maxId`, если что-то нашло, то добавлять новые записи. И конечно, это должно срабатывать только тогда, когда другие фильтры не изменились и не надо читать всю таблицу заново, т.е. нет вызова `model.setRowCount(0)`;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сделано 2 запроса max(id) к базе данных с разницей в 1000 миллисекунд и если max(id) не равны - выполняю нужный код.

```
Statement statement = connect.createStatement();
String sql = "select max(fl_id) from fs_log where fl_date > sysdate - " + where_clause;
ResultSet rs_id = statement.executeQuery(sql);
if (rs_id.next()) {
    max = rs_id.getInt(1);
}
statement.close();

try {
    Thread.sleep(1000);
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

Statement statement2 = connect.createStatement();
String sql2 = "select max(fl_id) from fs_log where fl_date > sysdate - " + where_clause;
ResultSet rs_id2 = statement2.executeQuery(sql2);
if (rs_id2.next()) {
    max2 = rs_id2.getInt(1);
}
statement2.close();

if (max != max2) {
    // код по заполнению 
}
```